# Databind a list with angular, using a mvc controller method

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am new with angular, so i hope this question is not to stupid.
as the title says, i wish to populate a list using angular and a method from a mvc controller. But i cannot figure out how to call the method? i have tried making a http request but i cannot get i to work.
Am i totally lost or is it somthing like this below?
Here are the list.

```
<div ng-app="cardList" ng-controller="CardController"></div>
<p><input type="text" ng-model="test" /></p>

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in names | filter:test">
        {{x}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

and here is the script.

```
<script>
var list = $http({ url: "Controllers/CardController/AllCardsList", method: "GET" });

angular.module('cardList', []).controller('CardController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.names = [list];
});
```

Comment: one thing i see, is that the first div should surround the other html elements. The <p> and <ul> tags are not running within angular, because the ng-app attribute is outside these tags

Comment: You need to use the .then method. have a look at the [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div ng-app="cardList" ng-controller="CardController">
  <p>
    <input type="text" ng-model="test" />
  </p>

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in names | filter:test">
      {{x}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and:

```
angular.module('cardList', []).controller('CardController', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("Controllers/CardController/AllCardsList").then(function(response){ 
    $scope.names = response.data;
  });
});
```

Comment: i have just tried this, but when i look in the console it gets a 404 error do you know why that could be?

Comment: Probably your url is not correct, and MVC cannot find it. You are mapping to a folder structure, rather than using MVC routing. Try "Card/AllCardsList" (assuming your controller is called "CardController" and your action is called "AllCardsList")

Comment: you are right the routing is wrong that is why. Hmm it looks like it is calling the model layer and then the controller for some reason

Comment: try testing your MVC backend using Postman or even your browser, before testing the angular app. This way you know where the problem is.

Comment: i have corrected the routing so that it should work. But i am still getting the 404 not found.

Comment: So using postman or your browser you are able to see the list of names? Now use that exact same url in the $http service, and things should work fine.

Comment: okay so now i got a new error. It says [filter:notarray] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/filter/notarray?p0=0. Is this somthing you have seen before? this is if i use track by index

Comment: This should be a separate SO question